# Extract Values to Table: wrong number of pixels

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, value-extraction

Using ArcGIS Pro and arcpy I am iterating through a shapefile using a SearchCursor to extract the pixel values of a raster for each polygon in the shapefile using the Extract Values to Table (Geostatistical Analyst) tool.

However, I noticed something strange - the number of pixels extracted for each polygon does not correspond to the right number of pixels encompassed by the polygon.

I have attached a figure as example - the polygon contains 20 pixels (figure 1).

[image]

However, only 9 are extracted by the tool (figure 2).

[image]

This is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_features,['SHAPE@', 'FID']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            try:
                print('processing row '+str(row[1]))
                arcpy.ga.ExtractValuesToTable(row[0], input_raster, workspace + 'dev')
```

Any idea of what is going on?